# How do I improve my performance with this singly linked list struct within my program?

Tags: c++, performance, linked-list

Hey guys, I have a program that does operations of sets of strings. I have to implement functions such as addition and subtraction of two sets of strings. I need to get it down to the point where performance if of O(N+M), where N,M are sets of strings. Right now, I believe my performance is at O(N*M), since I for each element of N, I go through every element of M. I'm particularly focused on getting the subtraction to the proper performance, as if I can get that down to proper performance, I believe I can carry that knowledge over to the rest of things I have to implement.

The '-' operator is suppose to work like this, for example.

Declare set1 to be an empty set.
Declare set2 to be a set with { a b c } elements
Declare set3 to be a set with ( b c d } elements

set1 = set2 - set3

And now set1 is suppose to equal { a }. So basically, just remove any element from set3, that is also in set2.

For the addition implementation (overloaded '+' operator), I also do the sorting of the strings (since we have to).

All the functions work right now btw.

So I was wondering if anyone could

a) Confirm that currently I'm doing O(N*M) performance
b) Give me some ideas/implementations on how to improve the performance to O(N+M)

Note: I cannot add any member variables or functions to the class strSet or to the node structure.

The implementation of the main program isn't very important, but I will post the code for my class definition and the implementation of the member functions:

**strSet2.h (Implementation of my class and struct)**

```
// Class to implement sets of strings

// Implements operators for union, intersection, subtraction,
//  etc. for sets of strings

// V1.1 15 Feb 2011 Added guard (#ifndef), deleted using namespace RCH

#ifndef _STRSET_
#define _STRSET_

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
// Deleted: using namespace std;  15 Feb 2011 RCH

struct node {
    std::string s1;
    node * next;
};

class strSet {

private:
    node * first;

public:
    strSet ();  // Create empty set
    strSet (std::string s); // Create singleton set
    strSet (const strSet &copy); // Copy constructor
    ~strSet (); // Destructor

    int SIZE() const;

    bool isMember (std::string s) const;

    strSet  operator +  (const strSet& rtSide);  // Union
    strSet  operator -  (const strSet& rtSide);  // Set subtraction
    strSet& operator =  (const strSet& rtSide);  // Assignment


};  // End of strSet class

#endif  // _STRSET_
```

**strSet2.cpp (implementation of member functions)**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include "strset2.h"

using namespace std;

strSet::strSet() {
    first = NULL;
}

strSet::strSet(string s) {
    node *temp;
    temp = new node;
    temp->s1 = s;
    temp->next = NULL;
    first = temp;
}

strSet::strSet(const strSet& copy) {
    if(copy.first == NULL) {
        first = NULL;
    }
    else {
        node *n = copy.first;
        node *prev = NULL;
        while (n) {
            node *newNode = new node;
            newNode->s1 = n->s1;
            newNode->next = NULL;
            if (prev) {
                prev->next = newNode;
            }
            else {
                first = newNode;
            }
            prev = newNode;
            n = n->next;
        }
    }
}

strSet::~strSet() {
    if(first != NULL) {
        while(first->next != NULL) {
            node *nextNode = first->next;
            first->next = nextNode->next;
            delete nextNode;
        }
    }
}

int strSet::SIZE() const {
    int size = 0;
    node *temp = first;
    while(temp!=NULL) {
        size++;
        temp=temp->next;
    }
    return size;
}    

bool strSet::isMember(string s) const {
    node *temp = first;
    while(temp != NULL) {
        if(temp->s1 == s) {
            return true;
        }
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    return false;
}

strSet strSet::operator +  (const strSet& rtSide) {
    strSet newSet;
    newSet = *this;
    node *temp = rtSide.first;
    while(temp != NULL) {
        string newEle = temp->s1;
        if(!isMember(newEle)) {
            if(newSet.first==NULL) {
                node *newNode;
                newNode = new node;
                newNode->s1 = newEle;
                newNode->next = NULL;
                newSet.first = newNode;
            }
            else if(newSet.SIZE() == 1) {
                if(newEle < newSet.first->s1) {
                    node *tempNext = newSet.first;
                    node *newNode;
                    newNode = new node;
                    newNode->s1 = newEle;
                    newNode->next = tempNext;
                    newSet.first = newNode;
                }
                else {
                    node *newNode;
                    newNode = new node;
                    newNode->s1 = newEle;
                    newNode->next = NULL;
                    newSet.first->next = newNode;
                }
            }
            else {
                node *prev = NULL;
                node *curr = newSet.first;
                while(curr != NULL) {
                    if(newEle < curr->s1) {
                        if(prev == NULL) {
                            node *newNode;
                            newNode = new node;
                            newNode->s1 = newEle;
                            newNode->next = curr;
                            newSet.first = newNode;
                            break;
                        }
                        else {
                            node *newNode;
                            newNode = new node;
                            newNode->s1 = newEle;
                            newNode->next = curr;
                            prev->next = newNode;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if(curr->next == NULL) {
                        node *newNode;
                        newNode = new node;
                        newNode->s1 = newEle;
                        newNode->next = NULL;
                        curr->next = newNode;
                        break;
                    }
                    prev = curr;
                    curr = curr->next;
                }
            }
        }
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    return newSet;
}

strSet strSet::operator - (const strSet& rtSide) {
    strSet newSet;
    newSet = *this;
    node *temp = rtSide.first;
    while(temp != NULL) {
        string element = temp->s1;
        node *prev = NULL;
        node *curr = newSet.first;
        while(curr != NULL) {
            if( element < curr->s1 ) break;
            if( curr->s1 == element ) {
                if( prev == NULL) {
                    node *duplicate = curr;
                    newSet.first = newSet.first->next;
                    delete duplicate;
                    break;
                }
                else {
                    node *duplicate = curr;
                    prev->next = curr->next;
                    delete duplicate;
                    break;
                }
            }
            prev = curr;
            curr = curr->next;
        }
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    return newSet;
}

strSet& strSet::operator =  (const strSet& rtSide) {
    if(this != &rtSide) {
        if(first != NULL) {
            while(first->next != NULL) {
                node *nextNode = first->next;
                first->next = nextNode->next;
                delete nextNode;
            }
        }
        if(rtSide.first == NULL) {
            first = NULL;
        }
        else {
            node *n = rtSide.first;
            node *prev = NULL;
            while (n) {
                node *newNode = new node;
                newNode->s1 = n->s1;
                newNode->next = NULL;
                if (prev) {
                    prev->next = newNode;
                }
                else {
                    first = newNode;
                }
                prev = newNode;
                n = n->next;
            }
        }
    }
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: Rob's right. Basically any operation of this type can be done in linear time if the lists are ordered. It's the general *merge* algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I believe your current `operator-` is O(N*M).

Since this is homework, I don't want to give you too much information, but ...

If your linked list were ordered, then you could write subtraction in O(N+M). This leaves two questions for you: how to keep the list ordered? and how to write an O(N+M) subtraction algorithm, given ordered lists.

Comment: The lists are guaranteed to be ordered, as per my implementation of the '+' operator. In my main program, when a strSet is built (ie, set1) it gets ordered. So by the time we can use '-' on it, its already ordered

Comment: Also, not really homework. The work needed to be done and handed in was just getting everything to work. Getting performance down is an extra option to improve knowledge and for practice purposes.

Comment: re: homeowrk. Sorry, when I read "our prof wanted a very simple implementation of a linked list", I assumed you were doing this at school at the request of a professor. I'll delete the 'homework' tag I added. You can write O(N+M) algorithm by walking the two lists in parallel. `new=empty; while(lhs != end && rhs != end) { if (*lhs == *rhs) { ++lhs, ++rhs } elsif (*lhs < *rhs) { new.add(*lhs++); } else { rhs++ } }  // then copy remaining items from rhs or lhs to new`

Comment: @Jesus: Rob Adams has a linear algorithm in his comment. He's basically recreated `std::set_difference` from the standard library.

Comment: Okay, cool. Thanks guys. I visualize how that can work, and I'm going to start trying to implement that now. That looks like it could work for '-' and '*', which is the intersection. With sorted lists, I can see how it would work for '+' too, but my implementation of '+' does the sorting as well.

Comment: @Jesus: For intersection you could just open the `<algorithm>` header file and see how they implement `std::set_intersection`...